# Kiu nivelo de domo estas la "unua etaĝo"?

Tags: numbers

La maniero per kiu oni kalkulas etaĝojn estas malsama en la germana kaj la sveda. En la sveda, la normo estas ke la "unua etaĝo" staras sur la grundo. Tie kie oni eniras la domon estas la unua etaĝo. Mi lernis ke en la germana la "unua etaĝo" estas super la surgrunda etaĝo. Kiel oni nombras etaĝojn en Esperanto? Kiu estas la unua etaĝo? Ĉu a aŭ b?

[image: Ĉu a aŭ b estas nomata "la unua etaĝo"?]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Vortaro.net](http://vortaro.net/) ankaŭ mencias ĉi tiun problemon:

> La maniero kalkuli la etaĝojn ne estas la sama por ĉiuj popoloj: iuj inkluzivigas la teretaĝon (do nomatan unua), aliaj ekskluzivigas ĝin.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that is a language-related issue as much as a cultural convention. There is a difference in British English and American English, and according to Wikipedia the main distinction goes across continents: Europe mainly starts counting at zero, while the USA and Canada start at one. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storey for details.

---

Mi ne pensas, ke ĝi estas lingva demando, sed kultura: vidu la artikolon en la angla Vikipedio. La [esperanta versio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eta%C4%9Do) ne enhavas utilan informon.

Answer (score 1):

Mi dirus, ke ĝi dependas de kiu lando vi estas.

Answer (score 1):

According to the book, ["Bridge of Words" by Esther Schor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VE3L7K4), this was decided by cultural convention according to Akademio de Esperanto as in User428's and Oliver Mason's answers above.  Please see the section "5. Big endians and Little endians" of "Samideanoj II- Iznik to Bialystok, or unu granda rondo familio"

Answer (score 0):

Eble ni povus ĉirkaŭiri la problemon uzante:

- grundo: teretaĝo
- etaĝoj supre: superteretaĝo

Ni havus

- teretaĝo
- la 1a superteretaĝo
- la 2a superteretaĝo
- k.t.p.

Same por la etaĝoj sube la tero:

- la 1a subteretaĝoj
- la 2a subteretaĝoj
- k.t.p.

Kion vi opinias?

Comment: Ĉu eblas ke oni povus kompreni superteretaĝo kiel supertero-etaĝo (grundo) anstataŭ super-teretaĝo (grundo + 1) ?

Comment: Interesa ideo, laux mi!